# How to query across multiple remote accumulo instances

Tags: distributed, accumulo

I'm new to accumulo and had a newbie question.

I have several independent, remote accumulo instances. I would like to run a single query across all the instances simultaneously and aggregate the results. Is there a library or a standard method/best practice of doing this ?

thx

Comment: What do you mean by "several independent, remote accumulo instances"?  How are those instances related?

Comment: Other than the client, they are not related. The should be considered vertical, independent systems maintained by different groups who cannot share other than with me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Accumulo-recommended way to do this. Like you consider them independent clusters, we would also consider them independent and rely on you, the user, to aggregate data you query from each. Given that Scanners and BatchScanners expose an Iterator, it is very straightforward to merge the results from each Iterator (Guava's Iterators class might be helpful).

Comment: Thanks, I thought that was the case. I posted the question to be sure